# Docker php-fpm can not delete Fastcgi Cache files of Nginx process

Tags: php, docker, nginx, fastcgi

I have a share volume moutn between nginx container and php-fpm container. By following this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-fastcgi-caching-with-nginx-on-your-vps, Nginx do create cache files. However, I can not delete it due to permission issue.
If I want to delete it from my php-fpm container. I have to go to inspect container and chown -R www-data:www-data the folder. Then Nginx create a new one and I have to do it again

```
drwx------    3 root     root      4096 Jan 31 10:58 b
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What user and group does nginx use, and what user and group does php-fpm use?

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana. nginx by default user 101:101 to create static cache files.
For php-fpm, it get default user 82:82.